# Get amount from SetExpressCheckout

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I create my payment system and in the `SetExpressCheckout` AMT param i set a variables because the price can change. So in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` param we also need the amount, but PayPal doesn't send it. How can I retrieve it.
Here is my code :

```
$amt = $_GET["AMT"];

$requete = construit_url_paypal();
$requete = $requete."&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout".
            "&CANCELURL=".urlencode("*").
            "&RETURNURL=".urlencode("*").
            "&AMT=$amt".
            "&CURRENCYCODE=EUR".
            "&DESC=".urlencode("Desc").
            "&LOCALECODE=FR";
```

And the other page :

```
$requete = $requete."&METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment".
            "&TOKEN=".htmlentities($_GET['token'], ENT_QUOTES).

            "&AMT=   REQUESTED_AMOUNT   ".

            "&CURRENCYCODE=EUR".
            "&PayerID=".htmlentities($_GET['PayerID'], ENT_QUOTES).
            "&PAYMENTACTION=sale";
```

Thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` API to get the transaction,buyer related information etc

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/